Identifier 'parse' has already been declared. Migrating project from Angular17 to Angular18
After upgrading to Angular18 and running the command 'npm run build:ssr', I got an error: Identifier 'parse' has already been declared
Full error message is:
 D:\angular-apps\sampleAngularApp\node_modules\cssstyle\lib\properties.js: Identifier 'parse' has already been declared. (5029:9)

  5027 | var width_export_definition;
  5028 |
> 5029 | function parse(v) {
       |          ^
  5030 |   if (String(v).toLowerCase() === 'auto') {
  5031 |     return 'auto';
  5032 |   } [plugin angular-compiler]

    node_modules/cssstyle/lib/CSSStyleDeclaration.js:225:8:
      225 │ require('./properties')(CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype);
          ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   This error came from the "onLoad" callback registered here:

    node_modules/@angular/build/src/tools/esbuild/angular/compiler-plugin.js:322:18:
      322 │             build.onLoad({ filter: /\.[cm]?js$/ }, (0, load_resul...
          ╵                   ~~~~~~

    at setup (D:\angular-apps\sampleAngularApp\node_modules\@angular\build\src\tools\esbuild\angular\compiler-plugin.js:322:19)
    at async handlePlugins (D:\angular-apps\sampleAngularApp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1194:20)

I have tried:

npm update
removed node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling packages
removed .angular cache folder
with different types of compalierOptions in the tsconfig.json file (I have set the 'target' property to ES2022, ES2023, or ESNEXT)

but no result. I stuck.
I'm attaching package.json file:
{
  "name": "sample-angular-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:pl": "ng build --configuration=pl",
    "build:it": "ng build --configuration=it",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run ngIwa:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/ngIwa/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run ngIwa:server",
    "prerender": "ng run ngIwa:pretender",
    "start": "ng serve  --proxy-config ./src/proxy.conf.json",
    "start:pl": "ng serve --configuration=pl --proxy-config ./src/proxy.conf.json",
    "start:it": "ng serve --proxy-config ./src/proxy.conf.json --configuration=it"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/material": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/ssr": "^18.2.0",
  "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
  "express": "^4.19.2",
  "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
  "mock-browser": "^0.92.14",
  "moment": "^2.30.1",
  "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~18.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.4.1",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  }

}
I use Node 20.16.0 and Angular CLI 18.2.0
I appreciate any help you can provide.

The function parse() was declared twice in the '\node_modules\cssstyle\lib\properties.js'. I have removed the first declaration and now it works.
